# Find 7 vertices of a box using openCV

Tags: numpy, opencv, contour

I don't know if this question have been repeating in here. If yes then i'm sorry..

[image]

I have a box that positioned to see H,W,L view. I understand steps to get vertices however most of the examples in the net only describes how to get 4 vertices from 2D plane. So my question is, how if we want to get 7 vertices (like the pic above) and handle it in numpy? How to differentiate between upper points and lower points?

[image]

I will be using Python to determine this.

Comment: can you post the original image without the dots? They make things harder. Also, how attached are you to that dot in the middle? The six on the outside are trivial. That middle dot can be approximated reasonably well with a simple assumption, but getting it precisely seems difficult.

Comment: @IanChu - Ok changed. For me precision is not necessary. I need a rough identification. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt to get the 8 corners of the 3d rectangle. I masked on the saturation channel of the HSV color space since that separates out white.

I used findContours to get the contour of the box and then used approxPolyDP to get a six-point approximation (the six visible corners).

From there I approximated the two "hidden" corners via a parallelogram approximation. For each point I looked two points behind and created a fourth point that would make a parallelogram with that side. I then took the centroid of these parallelogram points to guess the corner. I hoped that taking the centroid of the points would help even out the error between the parallelogram assumption and the perspective warping, but it did a poor job.

If you need a better approximation there are probably ways to estimate the perspective warping to get the corners.

[image]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random

def tup(point):
    return (int(point[0]), int(point[1]));

# load image
img = cv2.imread("box.jpg");

# reduce size to fit on screen
scale = 0.25;
h,w = img.shape[:2];
h = int(scale*h);
w = int(scale*w);
img = cv2.resize(img, (w,h));
copy = np.copy(img);

# convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv);

# make mask
mask = cv2.inRange(s, 30, 255);

# dilate and erode to get rid of small holes
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8);
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations = 1);
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel, iterations = 1);

# contours # OpenCV 3.4, in OpenCV 2 or 4 it returns (contours, _)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
contour = contours[0]; # just take the first one

# approx until 6 points
num_points = 999999;
step_size = 0.01;
percent = step_size;
while num_points >= 6:
    # get number of points
    epsilon = percent * cv2.arcLength(contour, True);
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True);
    num_points = len(approx);

    # increment
    percent += step_size;

# step back and get the points
# there could be more than 6 points if our step size misses it
percent -= step_size * 2;
epsilon = percent * cv2.arcLength(contour, True);
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True);

# draw contour
cv2.drawContours(img, [approx], -1, (0,0,200), 2);

# draw points
for point in approx:
    point = point[0]; # drop extra layer of brackets
    center = (int(point[0]), int(point[1]));
    cv2.circle(img, center, 4, (150, 200, 0), -1);

# do parallelogram approx to get the two "hidden" corners to complete our 3d rectangle
proposals = [];
size = len(approx);
for a in range(size):
    # get points backwards
    two = approx[a - 2][0];
    one = approx[a - 1][0];
    curr = approx[a][0];

    # get vector from one -> two
    dx = two[0] - one[0];
    dy = two[1] - one[1];
    hidden = [curr[0] + dx, curr[1] + dy];
    proposals.append([hidden, curr, a, two]);

    # debug draw
    c = np.copy(copy);
    cv2.circle(c, tup(two), 4, (255, 0, 0), -1);
    cv2.circle(c, tup(one), 4, (0,255,0), -1);
    cv2.circle(c, tup(curr), 4, (0,0,255), -1);
    cv2.circle(c, tup(hidden), 4, (255,255,0), -1);
    cv2.line(c, tup(two), tup(one), (0,0,200), 1);
    cv2.line(c, tup(curr), tup(hidden), (0,0,200), 1);
    cv2.imshow("Mark", c);
    cv2.waitKey(0);

# draw proposals
for point in proposals:
    point = point[0];
    center = (point[0], point[1]);
    cv2.circle(img, center, 4, (200, 100, 0), -1);

# group points and sum up points
hidden_corners = [[0,0], [0,0]];
for point in proposals:
    # get index and update hidden corners
    index = point[2] % 2;
    pos = point[0];
    hidden_corners[index][0] += pos[0];
    hidden_corners[index][1] += pos[1];

# divide to get centroid
hidden_corners[0][0] /= 3.0;
hidden_corners[0][1] /= 3.0;
hidden_corners[1][0] /= 3.0;
hidden_corners[1][1] /= 3.0;

# draw new points
for point in proposals:
    # unpack
    pos = point[0];
    parent = point[1];
    index = point[2] % 2;
    source = point[3];

    # draw
    color = [random.randint(0, 150) for a in range(3)];
    cv2.line(img, tup(hidden_corners[index]), tup(parent), (0,0,200), 2);
    cv2.line(img, tup(pos), tup(parent), color, 1);
    cv2.line(img, tup(pos), tup(source), color, 1);
    cv2.circle(img, tup(hidden_corners[index]), 4, (200, 200, 0), -1);
    
# show
cv2.imshow("Image", img);
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask);
cv2.waitKey(0);
```